# Apache using JRuby 

Tags: jrubyonrails

I am currently using application which is developed using JRuby on Rails. I have created application which heavily depends on JRuby internals. Now I am looking to host the application in dedicated server using Windows platform. Can anyone tell how we can host the application using JRuby on rails. There is a possiblity of doing it ruby on rails. We can use it Apache/IIS7. But there are no specific details given regarding how to do develop in JRuby on rails Windows based platform using Apache/IIS7. Can anyone help me how to host JRuby on rails in dedicated server ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Trinidad to deploy a Jruby on Rails application.  Trinidad uses Apache tomcat as it's application server and Tomcat is embedded in the Jruby gem so you don't need to host/administer your own Tomcat instance outside of the application.

https://github.com/trinidad/trinidad

simplest application (from command line at the root of your rails app):

jruby -S gem install trinidad
jruby -S trinidad

Comment: how do you deploy in production with trinidad? I imagine you don't login over ssh, and run the command on the command line.

Comment: We use trinidad_init_services to make use trinidad as a daemon (which will take care of unexpected restarts).  Also, trinidad has a hot deploy option built in, so you can touch a file (like tmp/restart.txt) in an after deploy hook to reload the app (we use capistrano and a recipe very similar to our passenger deploys).

Answer (score 0):

Trinidad is a fine solution, but I've found that if you're hosting on the windows platform a better solution might be war file deployment. Use the Warbler gem https://github.com/jruby/warbler to create a simple war file which is then deployed to a tomcat server. This seems to work better for the windows ecosystem -- especially if there is an existing tomcat server or argumentative Ops staff involved.

For super ease of use, Trinidad.
For existing Windows world and Administrators, tomcat and war file.